# posting data using Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I have two array of objects that I want to post to an API but it displays an error missing value for parameter: productDC

it seems that i have to pass ProductDc and buyerDC along with their data. for this I also tried

```
 $data_string = array({ProductDc"product_name" => "Electronics","price" => "200 usd"},
    buyerDC{"buyer_name" => "john mark","address" => "17 more strret"});
```

below is the informations

1.) **ProductDC**
pass it as array of objects
**product_name(string)

price (string)**

2.) **buyerDC**
pass it as array of objects
**buyer_name(string)

address (string**)

here is my code

```
<?php

$data_string = array("product_name" => "Electronics","price" => "200 usd",
"buyer_name" => "john mark","address" => "17 more strret"); 


$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "myapi.com", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json",  
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
echo $response; 

}


?>
```

Comment: If any API is giving you a response saying that some 'xyz' parameter is missing then it is pretty simple that you are not passing that parameter in the API call. In your case if it is saying that you are missing ProductDc or buyerDC parameter then you need to pass them in the POST data which you are not doing if we see the values you have put inside $data_string array. Read their API document properly to find out the proper set of parameters which is required in the API request and pass all parameters in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering below information that you have provided if they want a data in the format in which -

1.) ProductDC should be an array of objects containing -

product_name(string)

price (string)

2.) buyerDC should be array of objects containing-

buyer_name(string)

address (string)

Probably they are expecting the data in a different form which you may get by changing $data_string value as below -

```
$data_string = array(
                    "ProductDc"=>array(
                                    "product_name" => "Electronics",
                                    "price" => "200 usd"
                                ),

                    "buyerDC"=>array(
                                "buyer_name" => "john mark",
                                "address" => "17 more strret"
                              )
                );
```

Change your $data_string value to the one I posted above and check.

Comment: Please check if you are enclosing the values of "ProductDc" and "buyerDC" inside `array(...)` after `=>` while creating `$data_string` array